# trouble with nested_form gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

I'm setting up the nested_form gem as explained here: https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form.

The issue is my f.fields_for appears to come back empty. I don't have any errors but on the page I only see the 'Add a Location' link which does nothing.

The data model is Events => event_locations <= Locations, event_locations is acting as a junction object.

Here is the form in my view:

```
 <%= nested_form_for @event do |f| %>
    <%= @event.locations %>
    <%= f.fields_for :locations do |task_form| %>
      <%= task_form.text_field :name %>
      <%= task_form.link_to_remove "Remove this Location" %>
    <% end %>

    <p><%= f.link_to_add "Add a Location", :locations %></p>
  <% end %>
```

Here is my event controller :

```
def new
    logger.debug "*** before Event.new"
    @event = Event.new
    logger.debug "*** after Event.new"
    3.times do
      @event.locations.build
    end   
  end
```

event.rb

```
has_many :days_events
  has_many :events_locations
  has_many :locations, :through => :events_locations

  # Validations
  validates_presence_of :name

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations
```

event_location.rb

```
belongs_to :event
belongs_to :location

accepts_nested_attributes_for :location
```

location.rb

```
has_many :events_locations
has_many :events, :through => :events_locations


#validations
validates_presence_of :name

accepts_nested_attributes_for :events
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nested_forms gem is a bit old. I would recommend using ryan's code in the revised episode of his screen cast (http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised). I think you need the pro account to see it, but it's worth it.

Alternatively, follow the original screen cast (http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2) unrevised and free and use the code from that. That way you at least know what's going on.